# R - Correlation Matrix - How to plot with this data?

Tags: r, matrix, correlation

I have the data like below:

```
A B 100
A C 100
B D 80
A D 50
B C 5
B D 60
```

basically three columns column 1 and Column 2 are character columns and column 3 is an integer which represents percentage of match between Col1 and Col2. Now I would like to represent this data as a correlation matrix. How can I do the same?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on how to reconstruct the whole correlation matrix relatively simply using igraph:

```
library(igraph)
library(corrplot)

g <- graph.data.frame(df, directed = FALSE)
mat <- get.adjacency(g, attr = "V3", sparse = FALSE)
mat
#output
    A   B   C  D
A   0 100 100 50
B 100   0   5 60
C 100   5   0  0
D  50  60   0  0
 diag(mat) <- 100
 mat <- mat/100

 corrplot.mixed(mat, upper =  "shade", "number")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is already one answer, but here is an idea with only base functions

```
heatmap(
  xtabs(
    data = aggregate(V3 ~ V1 + V2, data, 'mean'), 
    formula = V3 ~ V1 + V2
  ), 
  Rowv = NA, 
  Colv = NA, 
  revC = T)
)
```

[image]